# Port number in svn-remote

Tags: git, git-svn

After I did `git svn init -T https://10.1.1.126/svn/nm/:443`

I got lines in config:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
        url = https://10.1.1.126/svn/nm
        fetch = :443:refs/remotes/origin/trunk
```

After

```
git svn fetch
```

I got error:

```
svn-remote.svn: remote ref '443:refs/remotes/origin/trunk' must start with 'refs/'
```

I suppose is it something related to port number? How to fix it?

Comment: What is the correct URL? You can check with this `git svn info`

Answer (score 0):

The port number must be after the hostname, not after the URL. So the correct URL would be `https://10.1.1.126:443/svn/nm/`. But as 443 is the default for HTTPS anyway, `https://10.1.1.126/svn/nm/` would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

The SVN URL is look like this

https://domain or ip:PORT/root directory of repo

https://192.168.1.2:443/svn

https://localhost:443/svn

https://192.168.1.2/svn

http://192.168.1.2:8080/svn

https://localhost:8080/svn